# user Intent send image path to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

sometime i running  App on my phone.problem is when i click Ok button after camera was pick photo up,at this moment!App' stop running!in fact,i wanna see Pic on another Activity!Is

take picture:

```
private void takePhoto() {
    String SDState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (SDState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        photoUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PIC_BY_TACK_PHOTO);
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.take_photo_rem,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.takePhoto_msg,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

album:

```
private void pickPhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PIC_BY_PICK_PHOTO);
}
```

onActivityResult: user intent send image uri

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        doPhoto(requestCode, data);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void doPhoto(int requestCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PIC_BY_PICK_PHOTO) {
        if (data == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.photo_err,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        photoUri = data.getData();
        if (photoUri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.photo_err,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    String[] pojo = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(photoUri, pojo, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(pojo[0]);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        picPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 14) {

                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error:" + e);
        }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "imagePath = " + picPath);
    if (picPath != null) {

        Intent startEx = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoPre.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(SAVED_IMAGE_DIR_PATH, picPath);
        startEx.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(startEx);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.photo_err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

}
```

preview image Activity!**is getIntent() seted null?**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    picPath = bundle.getString(KEY_PHOTO_PATH);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPath, options);
```

Comment: check whether your extras key value variable `SAVED_IMAGE_DIR_PATH` and `KEY_PHOTO_PATH` are same,

Comment: what was the error while closing app...??

Comment: Please also post the error. most probably it will be a null pointer. Please post the log and also mention on which line the error is coming. As lines are not available here, tell the code on which the error is coming

Comment: SAVED_IMAGE_DIR_PATH and KEY_PHOTO_PATH both are different param beteew activity!

Comment: Is that code completely no problem ?

Comment: logcat :`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.newpingziyi/com.example.newpingziyi.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.newpingziyi/com.example.newpingziyi.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - start camera for take image

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
File image = new File(imagesFolder, Const.dbSrNo + "image.jpg");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);   
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

2 - write below code in "onActivityResult"

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "/MyImages/");

    /*photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + Const.dbSrNo + "image.jpg");*/

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    options.inPurgeable=true;
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
            + Const.dbSrNo + "image.jpg",options);

    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bm);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object 

    byteImage_photo = baos.toByteArray(); 

    Const.imgbyte=byteImage_photo;
```

3 - generate one java file Const.java

```
public class Const {
    public static byte[] imgbyte = "";
}
```

4 - now display that image in your activity using

```
byte[] mybits=Const.imgbyte;
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mybits, 0, mybits.length, options);
yourImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: my App's logcat :`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.newpingziyi/com.example.newpingziyi.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.newpingziyi/com.example.newpingziyi.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: had you try above code?? using Const.java file for transfer image bytes to other activity?

Comment: i'm ain't,those friends wanted to see the Logcat,so...,now i'm start it

Comment: Const.dbSrNo！**dbSrNo** what's that

Comment: Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("here you can write your image path")....thats mine image path.